# Maybe Monad: Why flatMap is flat?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

After reading this great article about monads in Typescript: 
https://codewithstyle.info/advanced-functional-programming-in-typescript-maybe-monad/
I feel like I've managed to grasp everything except the subject of this question.

Can someone explain why `flatMap()` is flat unlike `map()`, given the only difference is the former accepts lambda with `Maybe` as a return value?

I perfectly understand why arrays can be "flattened", but I am not able to apply the meaning of the "flat" to monads.

Comment: Are you asking why it's *called* "flat map" or why it behaves the way it does?

Comment: Hi! I wonder why it's called so. See the last line I've just added to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say I have a Maybe `m: Maybe<Int>` and a function `f: Int => Maybe<String>`. Now the type of `m.map(f)` would be `Maybe<Maybe<String>>`. The type of `m.flatMap(f)` would be just `Maybe<String>`. So just like flattening an array of arrays to just an array, using `flatMap` instead of `map` on `Maybe`s turns maybes of maybes into plain maybes.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks. :-) It's so simple. However I didn't yet realise the true difference between map and flatMap, but that's a diff story.. Thanks!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev If you have a function `flatten<T>(m: Maybe<Maybe<T>>): Maybe<T>`, such that `flatten(Some(None)) = None`, `flatten(None) = None` and `flatten(Some(Some(x))) = Some(x)`, then `m.flatMap(f)` is equal to `flatten(m.map(f))` (for those `f`, for which `m.flatMap(f)` is type-correct). So, besides the fact that `map` also works with functions that don't produce maybes, the difference is the same as calling `flatten` on the result. Another way to think of it is that `Some(x).map(f)` will always produce another `Some`, while `flatMap` could produce a `None`.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that both `flatMap` and `selectMany` (as it used to be called, stemming from the .NET implementation) are just other names for the `bind` operator in languages like Haskell. All other monadic operators *can* be implemented using `bind`/`selectMany`/`flatMap`. Filter, for instance, could be implemented as `flatMap` where the selector returns either an empty collection or a collection containing the original item, depending on whether or not the predicate has been satisfied.

Comment: The point being that "flatMap" is a lot more powerful than just flattening arrays and mapping maybes. It's the mathematical backbone of modern functional programming.

Comment: Thank you sepp2k! It was hard to swallow but in the end it started clicking for me!

Comment: @cwharris, I didn't get so far to the selectMany, but when I do, I'll try to digest your writing, thanks :)

Comment: `selectMany == flatMap`. You can ignore `selectMany`, unless you're using Rx or Ix for .NET.

Comment: @cwharris Hmm. this is interesting detail! I think I saw `selectMany` in Rx (RxJS probably), now I know it is the same as `flatMap`. Now the new question arises, why they are named different if they represent the same thing? :D I mean the `selectMany` phrase doesn't mean anything near `flatMap`, i guess...

Comment: Haskell's `bind` operator comes from a mathematics background. `flatMap` was introduced to JavaScript as a function on the `Array` prototype, and I think (this is me guessing) Erik Meijer and his team at Microsoft chose `SelectMany` for Reactive Extensions because `flatMap` doesn't cover the full spectrum of what the operator can do, and `bind` is a little obscure considering most of the .NET community did not have a solid understanding of functional programming at the time. Rx ported to JS where it kept `selectMany` for some time before `rxjs` was rewritten by benlesh, trxcllnt, and others.